# Modeling of exact stick-slip-friction using Linear complementarity problems (LCP)

Tags: friction, newtonian-mechanics

Within my master's thesis, I try to model a machine elements and have to model the exact slipping and exact sticking between the bodies. So I noticed that such problems can be formulated as a LCP.

However I have difficulties at finding any literature where the usage is described well with examples..

I would like to have something like a 1-DOF model such a box on a plane pulled with a spring and friction modeled with coulomb or so.

I would be very grateful of mentioning any literature/sites which can bring me further.

I am really desperate at implementing the coulomb friction..